# Find smooth version of $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^x a^x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, geometric-series, smooth-functions, analytic-continuation

I want to find a smooth function $f$ such that for all positive integers $x$, $f(x)=g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is given below. In less mathy terms I want a smooth version of $g(x)$ constrained by its integer inputs. $$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^x a^x$$ I've been playing around with this on [Desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D971t.png) by plotting $g(x)$ and the formula for a geometric sum $\frac{1-a^{x+1}}{1-a}$ which seems like it could be close to an answer but other than that I have no idea where to go from here. I've thought about trying to differentiate but again, don't know how to do that with this function. Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is the condition on the constant $a$?

Comment: As written, $g(x)=(x+1)a^x.$ Did you want the summand to be $a^i?$ That would make it a geometric series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Now that I'm looking back at my work I realize I do want the summand to be $a^i$ which makes my question evaporate. Hard to find a solution when your doing the wrong problem lol. Thank you